# How to test a model with a has_one association with FactoryGirl when I am already creating the association in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, factory-bot

I have a User model which has_one Profile. The Profile is automatically created when I create the User like so;

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  after_create :create_profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This all works nicely and a default profile is created with every user.

I want to do some testing of my user model though and this is where I am struggling.

I am using FactoryGirl and want to create a user like so

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "user_#{n}@example.com"}
    sequence(:username) {|n| "user_#{n}"}
    password "secret"
    factory :activated_user do
      before(:create) {|user| user.activated = true}
      association :profile, factory: :profile_for_activated_user
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    factory :profile_for_activated_user do
      first_name "Johnny"
      last_name "User"
    end
  end
end
```

This is where things go wrong for me. The after_create callback (which I want) overrides the association created by FactoryGirl (on `FactoryGirl.create :activated_user`) so I end up with a blank profile and failed tests. Do I need to change the way I am creating the association in the model (which I shouldn't have to - I shouldn't have to modify my code to suit my testing tools) or is there a way of managing this in FactoryGirl? Should I just manually assign the profile attributes in my test after creating the User in FactoryGirl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the after_create callback like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    after(:build) { |user| user.class.skip_callback(:create, :after, :create_setting) }
  end
end
```

Comment: That's great, although after_build gave a deprecation notice. I used after(:build) and it works perfectly. Thanks.